# Reporting t-tests instead of simple linear regressions

Tags: regression, t-test

Many papers in health research based on observational data use the following format:

**Does A cause B?**

1. t-test A vs B (or chi-square, or whatever other test of dependence between two variables)
2. multiple regression of B on A, adjusted for suspected confounders
3. make heroic inferences

Why is the apparent "standard" to first run the t-test (or what have you)  instead of just running the analogous unadjusted linear model, which can then be more clearly compared to the multivariable linear model of interest? Is there some other advantage to doing it the "standard" way that I am missing?

Comment: I think you mean "1. t-test of difference in mean B across categories of A" or similar.

Comment: It depends - can you link to some examples? *Maybe* it's pointless, but we couldn't say for sure without seeing exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two situations: A is randomised and A is not randomised.

If A is randomised then the conventional wisdom is randomisation ensures lack of bias and subsequent regression adjustment will not hurt and may help estimate precision.  Against that Freedman's '[On regression adjustments to experimental data](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019688580700005X)' paper argues that such adjustments can introduce bias in small samples and increase or misspecify estimate precision.  [Lin 2013](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1365527200) (paywalled) provides a useful discussion of this dispute, summarised informally [here](http://blogs.worldbank.org/impactevaluations/regression-adjustment-in-randomized-experiments-is-the-cure-really-worse-than-the-disease), detailing the circumstances where regression adjustments will work well.  And in the comments to this answer @frank-harrell notes that regression adjustment may sometimes even be *required* to get an unbiased effect estimate.  (So much the worse for unadjusted estimates and initial t-tests...)

In any case, those on Freedman's side of this debate tend to require and appreciate having a t-test for differences in B as a function of A and will generally be willing to ignore subsequent modeling.

If A *isn't* randomised then you should in normal circumstances expect confounding -- why else do the multiple regression?  In that case I can't see any point to building a model e.g. the simple linear model for which the t-test is a test, that has an estimate that in advance you do not expect to identify the causal effect of A on B.  And then there are the precision considerations noted above.  It seems more sensible to cut straight to the task of identifying that effect by trying to statistically control for its confounders.

It would seem to be a better idea to use the space the t-test took up to vary the list of confounders in a way that encompasses the set of theoretically reasonable stories about what confounds and how it does so.

Comment: "I can't see any point to building models with effect estimates that you know are confounded." If I understand the implications of what you wrote, there goes astronomy, tectonic geology, the study of toxic effects in humans, and any other scientific inquiry not amenable to randomization.

Comment: The thought is that if you know there are confounders then there's a point to doing at least one of: a) randomising A, b) statistically controlling for confounders of the A-B relationship.

Comment: So if A is not randomised and you think there are confounders then your t-test will not identify a causal effect but your multiple regression might.  Hence there's no point in doing the t-test first.  What could it tell you that would alter your opinion of the multiple regression?

Comment: I've adjusted the answer text with the aim of warding off that particular interpretation.  There are certainly those that hold that view of randomisation.  I'm not one of them.

Comment: I think your answer addresses some very important points that I completely agree with, but given other reasons (cultural more than scientific, unfortunately) for needing to follow the general format I outlined, is there any compelling resason to do the t-test rather than the simple regression?

Comment: Regression is not used in randomized studies for confounder balancing.  It is used to absorb explainable outcome heterogeneity to increase precision and power.  For models such as binary logistic or Cox models, covariate adjustment allows one to get an unbiased estimate of the treatment effect whereas unadjusted estimates are biased due to non-collapsibility of odds/hazards ratios.

Comment: Quite so. I've rewritten to be hopefully less misleading.  Thanks also for prompting me to read up on interesting situation with logistic models which I otherwise wouldn't have known about.